# What things can make css development faster?

Tags: css

Thing which I use

```
* stylesheets
      o project.css
      o ie.css
      o print.css
      o reset.css
```

- [CSS Frame generator](http://lab.xms.pl/css-generator/)
- readymade collection of useful css classes
- [Edit CSS option of Web developer toolbar](http://www.idratherbewriting.com/2007/01/13/web-developer-firefox-extensions-makes-css-editing-easy/) because it shows live preview
- Firebug
- [Css type set](http://www.csstypeset.com/)
- [CSS Sprite Generator](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/)
- [Troubleshooting with `<base>`](http://www.askthecssguy.com/2009/03/troubleshooting_with.html)
- [Online CSS Editor](http://www.cssportal.com/online-css-editor/) to test styles
- [HTML Table Code Generator](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html-table-code-generator/)
- [Dynamic Dummy Image Generator](http://dummyimage.com/)
- [PxtoEm converter](http://pxtoem.com/)
- [MRI](http://westciv.com/mri/)
- [CSS Redundancy Checker](http://services.immike.net/css-checker/)
- [CSS Readibility](http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/files/posts/css-formatting/clean.php)
- [CSS-Tricks.com's snippet collection](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/)
- http://html-ipsum.com/
- [CSS Color Converter](http://maettig.com/?page=PHP/CSS_Color_Converter)
- [Debug CSS](http://www.imarc.net/communique/507-debug_css)
- [CSS Tidy online](http://csstidyonline.com/)
- [Form Style Generator](http://www.formstylegenerator.com/)

Any other tips?

Comment: The links you provided are very useful! I would +1 you but I'm out of votes.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/webide/index.html

Comment: @Alix: At your service. +1. :)

Comment: Oh, those links are really good! Now I need a vote. Help, anyone? :)

Comment: clearfix has saved me loads of time

Comment: Cool +1, but this is in fact subjective. Please edit and mark Community Wiki, or you will risk the topic getting closed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Experience, experience and once again - experience.

You may find helpful IDEs, generators etc. but in the end of the day, if you're a developer, your experience plays the most important role.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to ask this question you surely shouldn't be working on coding the CSS to fit the design mockups in front of you. That's my humble opinion.

BTW: This was in response to the original phrasing of your question: "How should I start coding CSS for the design mockups in front of me."

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a framework like the [960 Grid System](http://960.gs). Creating nice layouts and functional prototypes is done very quickly when you've got 960 within reach.

Comment: but it works in proportion and i get design with different width and  gutter size

Comment: If you want to be faster, settle on a standard.

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper IDE that gives you as much help as possible.

Intellij IDEA is not only a great Java IDE, it is also great for HTML/CSS editing:

- CSS editor
- CSS code completion
- CSS syntax & error highlighting
- CSS on-the-fly validation & intention actions
- Find/highlight usages
- Quick doc
- CSS Code Folding
- CSS Code formatting
- CSS Structure view
- Refactoring
- Auto-comment
- Goto declaration
- Show Content

See more here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/html_css_editor.html

Comment: You didn't ask for free ... some of the best tools out there are not free (although there are certainly some good free tools).

Comment: a back hoe isn't free either, but would you only want to use free plastic spoons you got to dig a ditch?

Answer (score 1):

[scaffold](http://wiki.github.com/anthonyshort/csscaffold/) will allow you to build your CSS in conceptual manner...

Comment: but this is only for php sites

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

In response to your update - I personally favor Firebugs CSS edit/preview/modify over WDT's. Its a lot more direct IMO.

IMO this is in general a bad practice. While the goal is to seperate the structure (xhtml) from the presentation (CSS) this is sometimes not completely possible for example having to wrap an element with several other elements so the design team can have drop shadows and rounded corners and the development team can have felxible height and width...

Anyhow the easiest thing to do is just start applying your styles to the elements... i dont understand what kind of pointers youre looking for - it might help if you give a quick overview of your current process.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 0):

using tables for layout

Comment: I don't think you'd save much time unless you have a fluid design. Most of the times tables just lower the entry level of coding as in - you only have to know html to get something basic, but on the long run you're actually faster with css.
Anyway, it's a wide known fact that using tables for layout are a bad practice so this probably was just a sarcastic answer, but if time and crossbrowser support is critical it's not such a bad idea (that is of course if you have no problems sleeping after this).

Comment: wait you just said css is faster in the long run. but to save time i could use tables?

Comment: +1, it's so true sometimes.  (you're only 11 pts away from 5K now!)  But seriously CSS gives you more control especially if you are working on a CMS.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain templating systems such as sass, that can work well on certain designs or large stylesheets.

If your designs are repetitive as in they always stick to certain convetions, you can try a css framework.

However, despite limited crossbrowser support, CSS is trivial (including IE6 after a certain amount of experience). You can try to combine templating systems, or so called css frameworks but take in mind that sometimes less is more.

Answer (score 0):

Like Hartikainen suggested I would strongly considered to use a **CSS Extension**. They truly simplify development, make your code more organized and support consistency. Therefore they support higher css quality and quicker development.

Most prominent are

- [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/),
- [Less](http://lesscss.org/) and
- [Compass](http://compass-style.org/)